# RAML API baseUriParameters unused template parameter error

Tags: rest, api-design, raml

I want to create a different base URI for each of the dozen customers of my API so the endpoints are the same but I can filter on customer. I think adding a template parameter to the base URI is the solution but how do I use the `baseUriParameter`?

I've imported a RAML spec into [APIMATIC](https://apimatic.io/) that has a `baseUriParameter`.

```
baseUri: http://{fi}.api.mycompany.com
baseUriParameters:
  fi:
    type: string
```

This template parameter gets added to each endpoint as a parameter. Here's an example endpoint.

```yaml
/users:
  get:
```

This gives an error message.

> "Endpoint Users has an unused template parameter named fi."

APIMATIC has a parameter added to the endpoint.
[image: APIMATIC Edit Parameter]

It also means no test cases have been auto-generated.

How do I use the `baseUriParameter`?

Comment: I've switched this around a bit so that the "fi" baseUriParameter is at the end.  `baseUri: https://api.mycompany.com/v{version}/{fi}`  APIMATIC doesn't recognise the template parameters but they are easy enough to add in later. This has cleared the problem but it doesn't count as a solution so it's not an answer to the question.

Comment: Hello @boggin. I am from APIMatic. I am looking at this and will get back to you very soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try importing your RAML API description file again. APIMATIC will use your `baseUri` and create template parameters now. You can checkout the `Server Configuration` page to see what parameters in the `baseUri` were recognized and set the default values for them as well.

[image]

Reference documentation for Server Configuration and template parameters in baseUri: https://docs.apimatic.io/api-editor/server-configuration/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Both the 'version' and the 'fi' where correctly added with the latest import of my API.